# Which augmented reality SDK offers best geolocation integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm looking for a good AR SDK that supports Unity and Google Maps integration. The SDK needs to be able to convert geocoordinates into Unity coordinates and can determine the surface height due to earth curvature. What SDK offers such capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Wikitude does it :

http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/JavaScript%20API/classes/GeoLocation.html

but Geolocation is not the primary purpose of AR. Most likely, marker recognition.